# Xpath: getting node attribute

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I'm trying to parse an XML file that looks like this:

```
<body>
<predictions>
<direction>
    <prediction epochTime="1400182631361" seconds="1109" minutes="18" isDeparture="false" dirTag="N__OB1" vehicle="1495" vehiclesInConsist="2" block="9708" tripTag="6041030"/>
    <prediction epochTime="1400182942181" seconds="1420" minutes="23" isDeparture="false" dirTag="N__OB1" vehicle="1515" vehiclesInConsist="2" block="9709" tripTag="6041031"/>
    <prediction epochTime="1400183687220" seconds="2165" minutes="36" isDeparture="false" dirTag="N__OB1" vehicle="1481" vehiclesInConsist="2" block="9710" tripTag="6041032"/>
    <prediction epochTime="1400183966372" seconds="2444" minutes="40" isDeparture="false" affectedByLayover="true" dirTag="N__OB1" vehicle="1520" vehiclesInConsist="2" block="9712" tripTag="6041033"/>
    <prediction epochTime="1400184566372" seconds="3044" minutes="50" isDeparture="false" affectedByLayover="true" dirTag="N__OB1" vehicle="1430" vehiclesInConsist="2" block="9713" tripTag="6041034"/>
</direction>

</predictions>
</body>
```

I'd like to extract all the `seconds` attributes inside each `prediction` node with Xpath (via "/body/predictions/direction/@seconds"), but it's not returning anything for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
//prediction/@seconds
```

The double `/` selects all rows while the `@` select the attribute you want. Your query returns nothing because you are trying to get the `seconds` attribute of `direction` which of course is non existent.